# Using jquery find() to get an attribute value from an XML doc

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to call an external XML feed and assign attribute values to a var to be used later in my HTML.

Example of the XML structure:

```
<Results>
  <ResultSet id="results1">
   <Listing rank="1" title="Test-Title">...</Listing>
   <Listing rank="2" title="Another-Title">...</Listing>
  </ResultSet>
  <ResultSet id="results2">
   <Listing rank="1" title="Don't Need">...</Listing>
   <Listing rank="2" title="Don't Need">...</Listing>
  </ResultSet>
</Results>
```

Example of my current code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'example.com?xml=1,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(data){
    console.log(data),
    xmlDoc = $.parseXML(data),
    $xml = $(xmlDoc),
    $Title1 = $xml.find('ResultSet[id="results1"] > Listing[rank="1"]').attr("title"),
    console.log($Title1);
...
```

I'm trying to get the value for the title attribute for a specific listing.  I think that my only problem is with the find().

Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Don't call `$.parseXML()`, this is done automatically when you use `dataType: "xml"`

Comment: And you don't need `$(xmlDoc)`, it does that automatically as well.

Comment: Man thank you, everything is working now :)